# listings style within both environments and inline

Tags: listings

I am trying to use `listings` to create some code. The MWE below works and produces the desired output. The problem is that everything is created twice, in that if I want to change the keyword colour to red I need to make two edits instead of just one. So in some sense I want to use `\lstset` within `lstinline` or somehow make use of `Rstyle` within `lstnewenvironment`. I tried combinations of these by trial and error and only seemed to have errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\lstnewenvironment{R}{\lstset{
  language=R,
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30!white},
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{black}},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
}}{}


\lstdefinestyle{Rstyle}
{
  language=R,
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30!white},
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{black}},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
}

\newcommand{\Rinline}[1]{\lstinline[style=Rstyle]{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\begin{document}

\begin{R}
x <- length(db[db=="Red"])
\end{R}


\Rinline{x <- length(db[db=="Red"])}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Erh, why aren't you just using the `Rstyle` in the definition of the environment? `style=Rstyle`, see also how I did my SASnRdisplay package, it is on CTAN

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know about that!

Comment: You should do `\newcommand{\Rinline}[1][]{\lstinline[style=Rstyle,#1]}`, so you're able to use both `\Rinline{<text>}` or `\Rinline|<text>|` (and have less problems overall). You can also add options to `\Rinline` with `\Rinline[<options>]{<text>}` or `\Rinline[<options>]|<text>|` (usual `verbatim` conventions apply).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple just use `style=Rstyle` in your env definition.

I use this extensively in my SASnRdisplay package

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are expecting `columns=fixed` tag, and the tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\lstnewenvironment{R}{\lstset{
  language=R,columns=fixed,
%  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30!white},
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{black}},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
}}{}


\lstdefinestyle{Rstyle}
{
  language=R,columns=fixed,
%  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30!white},
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{black}},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
}

\newcommand{\Rinline}[1]{\lstinline[style=Rstyle]{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\begin{document}

\begin{R}
x <- length(db[db=="Red"])
\end{R}

\noindent
\Rinline{x <- length(db[db=="Red"])}


\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note that I've removed the option `backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30!white}` from your `MWE`...